# running totals automatically inserted reset every 9 rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 4 users use to log hours and other info in. The columns are totalised and displayed at the top.

What I would like to do is in a column, say L, number 1 - 9 every nine lines (rows) starting at row 6  (row number to be defined) and in another column, say M, insert the running total of the nine lines of the value in column I.

The reason for the running total is that it needs to be transferred in paper-based logbooks which have 9 lines per page.

Hope that makes sense?

How would you go about doing this and is it an equation or a macro I would need?

In the screenshot[image] I would like to automatically add columns L and M. M is based on the value in I

L and M are the values under Page totals and I is the flight time.

[test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qySIgtlikoNa8lK2qE5PqD1esWoF0fSGfUTX5UBp0RE/edit?usp=sharing)

update 1: I have solved the counting with the following in L7 and then dragged down

> =if(L6+1 < 10, L6+1,1)

Update 2: nearly working using the below in M7 and dragging it down, however, when column I is blank it still adds a number instead of leaving the cell blank!

```
=if(L7=1,
I7,
if(ISBLANK(I7), " ", M6+I7)
)
```

Comment: it's a bit tough to do in the abstract, but it's definitely do-able.  Can you share an EDITable sample spreadsheet?

Comment: @MattKing i have added a test sheet

Comment: Can you explain `the running total of the nine lines of the value in column D.`? Also please update your question to match the columns in the test spreadsheet to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formulae:

For column L, you can use an `ARRAYFORMULA` with the `MOD` operator, paste the following into `L6`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MOD((ROW(L6:L) + 3),9) + 1)
```

For column M, use `L7 = 0` instead of `ISBLANK(L7)`, paste this in `M6` and drag down:

```
=IF(L6 = 1, I6, if(I6 = 0, " ", M5 + I6))
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you. I don't how the arrayformula works so will google that later! is there a way to not output the line number if "I" is blank? as per the running total?

Comment: Just got it working by using =ARRAYFORMULA(if(I6:I =0 ," ",MOD((ROW(L6:L) + 3),9) + 1))